# Meteor MongoDB query with AND and OR

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I want a query in mongo db like this one in SQL:

```
Select * from Users 
where familyId =@X and (isDeleted =false or isDeleted is null)
```

already I have first condition, I don't know how to mixed it with And-Or

```
var myMembers = Meteor.users.find({ "profile.family_id":      Meteor.user().profile.family_id });
```

how should it be possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can explicitly query with the **[`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/)** operator as:

```
var family_id = Meteor.user().profile.family_id,
    myMembers = Meteor.users.find({ 
        "$and": [
            { "profile.family_id": family_id },
            {
                "$or": [
                    { "isDeleted": false },
                    { "isDeleted": null } /* or { "isDeleted": { "$exists": false } } */
                ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

or implicitly by specifying comma-separated expressions:

```
var family_id = Meteor.user().profile.family_id,
    myMembers = Meteor.users.find({ 
        "profile.family_id": family_id,
        "$or": [
            { "isDeleted": false },
            { "isDeleted": null } /* or { "isDeleted": { "$exists": false } } */
        ]
    });
```

---

**Note**: To check whether a field exists, you can use the [**`$exists`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator as `{ "isDeleted": { "$exists": false } }` since the `{ isDeleted : null }` [query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-for-null-fields/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls) matches documents that either contain the `isDeleted` field whose value is null or that do not contain the `isDeleted` field.

Comment: It does work. Thanks